# Aria roles group or listbox for Material design card?

Tags: accessibility, materialize, roles, wai-aria

For designs similar to this the image card used on Materialize: http://materializecss.com/components.html#
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlrdh.jpg

Should I be using roles of a group or listbox for properly describing the content? I'm a tad lost reading through the aria accessibility specs.

Basic Structure:

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
            <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>  
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>Card Content</p>
            <a href='#'>Authors</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
</div>
```

Side question on possibly how to deal properly addressing the links for multiple authors.

Comment: What makes you think that `group` or `listbox` could be appropriate here?

Comment: The roles spec made it seem like one or the other was the more appropriate descriptor. Is there one better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this to be a figure with a figcaption.

I would mark this up as follows(in Jade):

```
figure
    div.card-image
        img(src="", alt="If needed, any descriptive text here will be spoken by a screen reader, but will not be visible")
        span.card-title Card Title
    figcaption Anything within this figcaption tag will automatically be spoken by the screen reader
    a.card-action(href="#") This is a link
```

In this case, **there is no need at all to use any ARIA attributes**. All that is needed is semantic markup. I hope this helps.